# Single page Drupal apps with custom theme

Tags: services

I have a static HTML page which contains navigation that links to different sections on the same page. Just like this one http://www.cedricvella.com/#node-3 .

What I would like to know is how can this functionality be built with Drupal when creating a custom theme. I don't want to use Panels.

Is there a way you can pull each page node into one single page?

Comment: Have you lookup https://drupal.org/project/single_page_website module ?

Comment: I have indeed, However it only works with sub-theming Zen or Bartik. My theme is completely custom.

Answer (score 0):

you could do it using the [single page module](https://drupal.org/project/single_page_website). Each menu item can be a single page which can be mapped to a node.

Comment: Can I use single page module with a custom theme? The module page states it can only be used with Bartik and Zen.

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is to create a custom tpl for that page. define custom ID's on the div's for blocks that contain the information that you need to scroll to, and use a little jQuery to make the scroll smooth or add any other effects you want.

Comment: I've been checking out the Services module. Could be an option for pulling in node data to each section in my site.

Answer (score 0):

Closing this question. It seems the simplest answer is to use panels with custom panel layouts. However I like the idea of decoupling Drupal's back end from my front end app and feed the data using Web services. It's a good solution for single page applications.